# Replace whole table by a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to replace a whole table by a parameter?
I would like to write a statement which looks like this:

```
declare @tab as nvarchar(100);
set @tab = 'dbo.tblCostCenters';
select * from @tab;
```

However, this does not work. 
So the only other way I know so far is to create dynamic SQL. But this then is subject to SQL Injections. Is there possibly a better solution  ?

Comment: No. You have to use dynamic SQL to do something like that. Build up your SQL in an nvarchar variable, and then pass the variable to the EXE function.

Comment: And how to prevent SQL-injection in this case ?

Comment: What is the need for such a generic piece of code?

Comment: Validate the table name passed in with something like IF OBJECT_ID(@tab) IS NOT NULL THEN execute the code.  This validates that what is passed in is exactly and only a valid table name... anything else will skip the execution of the dynamic code.

Comment: @pmbAustin `"table1; DROP TABLE table2"` can be a valid table name. Checking the OBJECT_ID won't save table2 when `'SELECT * FROM '+@tab` is executed.

Comment: Not in my testing.  OBJECT_ID('validTableName; DROP TABLE someTable') returns NULL every time I try it.  But even if it didn't, you could further do an EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tab) as well.

Comment: @pmbAustin Like any other table, you have to create it first, i.e.: `CREATE TABLE "table1; DROP TABLE table2" (a int)` The point is checking that a table exists is not that same as making sure the table name doesn't include malicious code.

Comment: Sorry, this is not my experience. The OBJECT_ID method returns NULL even when both tables exist, and if you're paranoid about that, then further testing if the value is in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES pretty much protects you. I'm not seeing the problem you're asserting exists.

Comment: @pmbAustin I don't think you are understanding what `CREATE TABLE "table1; DROP TABLE table2" (a int)` is actually doing. Malicious code can masquerade as the name of an object. That code now lives in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.  When you are in a situation where you are using dynamic table names, trusting a table name simply because it exists is extremely insecure.

Comment: And I don't think you're understanding that what I typed above works perfectly well in the case described... you'd have to be stupid enough to let free-form text entry serve as a table name for a dynamic CREATE TABLE statement in your example, which... isn't part of this problem discussion at all, and thus not exactly relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it.  [**It is a bad idea.**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases)

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql =
  'SELECT * FROM '
  + ISNULL(QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@tab,2))+'.','')
  + QUOTENAME(PARSENAME(@tab,1))
WHERE OBJECT_ID(@tab,'U') IS NOT NULL

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: There's are many safety checks you could do.  None of them are a substitute for a better approach to the problem.